# Noncyclic subgroups of multiplicative group of integers mod n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to find an $n$ such that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$ has a noncyclic subgroup, and I'm struggling to think of an example of such a subgroup. How can I construct such a subgroup without thinking about the cyclic subgroups generated by the elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{\times}$?

Comment: Not difficult.  Try many values of $n$ upto 25 which are non-primes, The numbers being small, calculation (for example multiplication mod 18) is not really a struggle.  Find out  the orders of individual elements, and compare with the order of group. A routine work taking less than 15 minutes would provide the answer you seek.

Comment: Idea: $(\Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z)^\times$ is cyclic $\iff$ $n=2,4,p^a,2p^a$ where $p$ is an odd prime. So for those $n$'s, the group is cyclic and hence subgroups are also cyclic. So you work with other $n$'s

Comment: See entries larger than $2$ in https://oeis.org/A060594.

Answer (score 1):

Take the group $U(20)=\{1,3,7,9,11,13,17,19\}$ and its subgroup $S=\{1,9,11,19\}$. Since $9^2\equiv 11^2\equiv 19^2\equiv 1\bmod 20$, all elements different from $1$ have order $2$. Hence $S\cong C_2\times C_2$ is not cyclic. Furthermore, then also $U(20)$ cannot be cyclic.

Comment: I like your example. I've been playing around recently with last digits $\{1,3,7,9\}$ in $\text{modulo-}100$ and $\text{modulo-}1000$ systems - they identify the units. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

If $(\Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z)^\times$ contains a non-cyclic subgroup then $(\Bbb Z /n \Bbb Z)^\times$ itself must be non-cyclic.

A non-cyclic group must have at least $4$ elements.

Since $(\Bbb Z /8 \Bbb Z)^\times = \{1,3,5,7\}$ contains $4$ elements, we can check if it is also non-cyclic:

$\; 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$
$\; 3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$
$\; 5^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$
$\; 7^2 \equiv 1 \pmod8$

So $(\Bbb Z /8 \Bbb Z)^\times$ is a non-cyclic group.

Comment: This is the smallest example for such a group itself  (+1).